# Is name of interface be able to be different from name its class within? [c++]

Tags: c++, class, interface, namespaces, filenames

I am writing up a simple C++ program whose interface and implementation are separated.
Both of them contains only one class.
Is it OK if the I keep the name of the interface and implementation the same, while using a different name of that class within?

Comment: C++ interface would be a base type with pure virtual members.. since it doesn't have native interfaces. Then you would normally derive from it to create the implementation - Hence they can't have the same name. Maybe I misunderstood your question.. can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just wonder if it's OK to have a header file and an implementation file named like"a.h" and "a.cxx", meanwhile naming the class within like "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is OK to do what you described. For instance, the below can be used when you want to hide the interface implementation details.

```
 // foo.h
class Foo
{
    public virtual void bar() = 0;
};

// foo.cpp
class FooImpl : public Foo
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        // do something
    }
};

// factory
Foo* Foo::Create()
{
    return new FooImpl();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as the C++ language and compiler are concerned, you can name your classes anything you like; class names do not need to be in any way related to the names of the files that contain their interface or their implementation.  It's even perfectly legal to have multiple classes declared together in a single .h or .cxx file.

From a style perspective, other programmers might find it easier to understand your source code if you keep your class names matching your file names, but it's really up to you whether you want to do that or not.

Comment: `other programmers might find it easier to understand` - and that is no small concern! **"Programs are meant to be read by humans and only incidentally for computers to execute"** (from the book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*).